# Rails 4 Concurrency Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, concurrency, mutex

I am having an hard time figuring out the reason why my model is behaving like this.

It has 2 actions, **cancel** and **feature**, when attribute was already canceled it shouldn't be available to be featured.

To ensure that a *feature* is not performed on a canceled attribute I am using [Redis-Mutex](https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex) to lock the attribute for exclusivity and make the proper verifications inside the block. This should ensure that records being worked out on one side are not simultaneously being worked on the other:

**Feature Action:**

```
mutex = RedisMutex.new(record_to_feature, block: 30, sleep: 0.1)
if mutex.lock
    record_to_feature = record_to_feature.reload

    if record_to_feature.reload.active?
        record_to_feature.reload.update_attributes(featured: true)
    end
    mutex.unlock
end
```

**Cancel Action:**

```
mutex = RedisMutex.new(record_to_cancel, block: 30, sleep: 0.1)
if mutex.lock
    record_to_cancel = record_to_cancel.reload

    if !record_to_cancel.reload.featured?
        record_to_cancel.reload.update_attributes(active: false)
    end
    mutex.unlock
end
```

I want to understand how is it possible that sometimes (rare) the attribute is first canceled and then featured - the other way: feature and then cancel may also occur just I haven't detected it.

Please let me know if this is a bad approach and if yes what would be a good way to fix this issue.

Comment: As far as I understand there is no possible way that both actions are being accessed at the same time (problem in mutex), so what I suspect is that by some reason when the second action is called / gets the lock and reads the attributes (with .reload) they still are not updated by some reason (outdated info supplied by database) and because of that the second action is performed. The question is the same... why is this happening?

Comment: The only things that make sense are a timeout after 30 seconds (maybe when the underlying database is unavailable for that long) or a bug in RedisMutex. Though these won't be the cause of the trouble, 1) all but the first `reload` in each method are wastefully querying the db while you already have the lock. And 2) I wonder why you're not using the native database `:lock` rather than redis?  (Maybe you're using a db that doesn't support row locking?)

Comment: Oh, one other thing: RedisMutex lock keys are string concats of class name and object id (https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex/blob/master/lib/redis_mutex.rb#L20).  If you're using an AR class hierarchy (e.g. for single table inheritance), you could end up with different locks for the same underlying table row.

Comment: after carefully checking the logs and other elements available, I can see that on the last time this issue occured, the element was canceled 6 seconds before, and just 6 seconds later the feature was called, got re-locked and then featured, so I think the whole problem is not on the mutex and concurrency thing I highlighted on this but on the point of how it passed this condition after the cancelation: `if record_to_feature.reload.active?`

Comment: Okay. That's great detective work. As I said, all reloads except the first in each mutex block are not accomplishing anything. Give what you said, you should scour the system for other updates that are taking place outside the lock.

Comment: Is't the mutex supposed to be assigned in a shared fashion, like a constant, so it's not re-instantiated between actions?

Comment: Do you actually see the sequence cancel then feature, or, do you discover the state active == false, featured == true? Your logic does not set featured to false on cancel.

Comment: @JimFlood by default / before updates active is true and featured is false; record_to_cancel and record_to_feature are meant to be the same record, I just gave different names for the explanation.

Comment: @ace see my answer below for more information on what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I finally found the problem.

On redix-mutes, I should use the non-blocking mode to avoid these kind of issues.

This way if the lock couldn't be made in first instance, the process will be aborted and no problems are created.

The way I had id (block 30 seconds) it was trying for 30 seconds (polling intervals of 100ms) to establish a lock and somehow that could cause multiple issues like these. Example: two threads trying to get the lock on a record and the last one establishes it first.

> The lock method returns true when the lock has been successfully
>   acquired, or returns false when the attempts failed after the seconds
>   specified with :block. When 0 is given to :block, it is set to
>   non-blocking mode and immediately returns false.

https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex

Answer (score 5):

When active == true and featured == false, you can invoke the feature action. This will set featured to true since active == true.

Then you can call the cancel action. Since featured == true, action is set to false.

Now, active == false and featured == true.

I drew up a simple state diagram to show all the possible changes of state. I did not include no-op state changes, for example, you can call the feature or cancel actions when both active and featured are false, but this won't do anything.

The arrows all represent paths where update_attributes is called. The circles represent the different states that the record can be found in.

There may not be a state where both active and featured are both false -- I don't see how the record is constructed so I include this for completeness.

It is easy to see how the record can be featured, yet, not active.

[image: state changes]

EDIT:

Here is an updated state diagram with your if statement fixed, and simplified:

[image]

So it seems not possible to cancel, then feature.

One thing that occurs to me is that you are not checking the return value from update_attributes to see if the update was successful. Could a failed update explain the observed behavior?

Comment: god damn, what a dumb I made the question incorrectly! the condition for the cancel is in negatory: if !record_to_cancel.reload.featured? I apologise for this and the question was already updated!